# Laravel Spatie Multitenancy: specific migration for specific tenant

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I use [spatie/multitenancy](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/introduction) version 1 with Laravel 7.x. As I am new to multitenancy, I am stuck with the following problem.

Normally when I make a migration, all tenants database will be migrate. Instead of this, if I want to migrate specific migration file for specific tenant database, how can I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand from [the docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v1/advanced-usage/making-artisan-commands-tenant-aware#running-artisan-command-for-specific-tenants), you can specify you can run the `tenants` artisan command for a specific tenant with the `tenant` option. E.g

`php artisan tenants:artisan "migrate --seed" --tenant=123`

Where `tenant` is the tenant's id.

Comment: But, when I try to run `php artisan tenants:artisan "migrate --path=/database/migrations/my_migration.php" --teant=1`. It doesn't work. Because I want to run specific migration file for specific tenant.

Comment: @Cloud You have a typo in the command you pasted: `teant` should be `tenant`. Does this change the outcome?

Comment: After modify typo error, that migration file is insert into `landlord` database, instead of tenant database. So I try again with --database like this `php artisan tenants:artisan "migrate --path=database/migrations/2021_04_23_035923_create_materials_table.php" --tenant=2 --database=tenant`. But, it shows error `The "--database" option does not exist.`

Comment: Oh, I got it.  `php artisan tenants:artisan "migrate --path=database/migrations/2021_04_23_035923_create_materials_table.php --database=tenant" --tenant=2`. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @Cloud. Please consider accepting or upvoting this answer if it helped you or solved your problem. See stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers